# What size should the ImageList for a ListView be?

Tags: c++, windows, listview, size, imagelist

I have a ListView, and I don't know how big to make the ImageLists for large and small, and group header icons. How big should they be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest

32x32 pixels for large and group header

ex. in MFC

```
// The pointer to my image list.
extern CImageList* pmyImageList;
pmyImageList->Create(32, 32, ILC_COLOR8, 0, 4);
```

small might be 16x16.

see here for *possible* insight into Microsoft's sizing recommendations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997636.aspx